# SQL subQuery with COUNT() in WHERE/HAVING Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Consider following subquery. This query retrieves all the personalIds of employees who have more then 1 'IDKleerkastPersoon' in their possession. For this query i'm useing a **COUNT**() statement in my **HAVING** Clause. This subuqery returns all the the PersonalIds for there employees.

```
(SELECT     DISTINCT Persoon_1.Stamnr
 FROM          dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon AS KleerkastPerPersoon_1 INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.Persoon AS Persoon_1 ON KleerkastPerPersoon_1.ID_Persoon = Persoon_1.ID_Persoon
                        GROUP BY Persoon_1.Stamnr, Persoon_1.ID_Afdeling, KleerkastPerPersoon.IDKleerkastPersoon, Persoon.Naam
                        HAVING      (Persoon_1.ID_Afdeling = 2) AND (COUNT(KleerkastPerPersoon.IDKleerkastPersoon) >= 2)
                        ORDER BY Persoon_1.Stamnr DESC)
```

Now user requested some more information then solely the PersonalId of the employees. So I wrote a query above it (see below) which retrieves more global info about the employee. As expected, sql server rejects this method.

```
SELECT     dbo.Persoon.Stamnr, dbo.Persoon.Naam, dbo.Persoon.Voornaam, dbo.Refter.RefterOmschrijving, dbo.Kleedkamer.KleedkamerOmschrijving, 
                  dbo.Kleerkast.KleerkastOmschrijving
FROM         dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Persoon ON dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon.ID_Persoon = dbo.Persoon.ID_Persoon INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Kleerkast INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Kleedkamer ON dbo.Kleerkast.ID_Kleedkamer = dbo.Kleedkamer.ID_Kleedkamer INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Refter ON dbo.Kleedkamer.ID_Refter = dbo.Refter.ID_Refter ON dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon.ID_Kleerkast = dbo.Kleerkast.ID_Kleerkast
WHERE     (dbo.Persoon.Stamnr IN <<<Result of my first subquery>>>
                     )
```

The error message being thrown is:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the where clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a having clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference
```

So i moved my subquery to the having clause:

```
<<<Query 2>>>
HAVING      (dbo.Persoon.Stamnr IN
                      (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Persoon_1.Stamnr
                        FROM          dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon AS KleerkastPerPersoon_1     INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.Persoon AS Persoon_1 ON KleerkastPerPersoon_1.ID_Persoon = Persoon_1.ID_Persoon
                        GROUP BY Persoon_1.Stamnr, Persoon_1.ID_Afdeling
                        HAVING      (Persoon_1.ID_Afdeling = 2) AND (COUNT(KleerkastPerPersoon.IDKleerkastPersoon) >= 2)
                        ORDER BY Persoon_1.Stamnr DESC))
```

But now the query doesn't return any results. While I should be seeing 98 different records. Does any of you have a solution to my problem or my workaround? How can i remove the need for a subquery for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the result of first subquery in a table variable and then use it in your final query. Also no need of Order By clause in the subquery unless you are using TOP.

Comment: Nicely noted. That 'Order By' is in fact redundant. Will follow up your advice and create a temptable with the results for my first query.

Answer (score 1):

Well If I get what you are after something like

```
SELECT dbo.Persoon.Stamnr, dbo.Persoon.Naam, dbo.Persoon.Voornaam, dbo.Refter.RefterOmschrijving, dbo.Kleedkamer.KleedkamerOmschrijving, dbo.Kleerkast.KleerkastOmschrijving
FROM dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon
inner join (your original query) SomeSuitableAlias
On SomeSuitableAlias.Stamnr = dbo.KleerkastPerPersoon.Stamnr
```

should do the job.

Comment: You could make your original query a CTE as suggested by mhasan and join to that, if nothing else it helps readability.

Comment: Both methods were immensly usefull, both worked as well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the aggregate in the error message refers to the `GROUP BY` clause and the `COUNT(KleerkastPerPersoon.IDKleerkastPersoon)` in your first query.

When you use this select as a sub-query, you are apparently referencing something which is not the result of a `HAVING` clause or a `SELECT` statement. You should include any columns or aggregates you need in the result set of your sub-query. You should also leave the `ORDER BY` part out in the sub-query (assuming you haven't done so).

I can't see exactly what the offending reference is, but I agree with mhasan, that you should, at least initially, break your query down by using some temporary tables and when you get it working put it all back together into a single query.